# How to determine how big is the treasure map (rows and columns) from a textfile?

Tags: java, arrays

I'd like to know how to figure out the rows and columns of a passed textfile. 
Suppose the textfile looks like this:

```
X...................
....................
....................
....................
....................
....................
....................
....................
....................
..X.................
```

This textfile has 10 rows and 20 columns and I'm facing troubles with how to get those rows and columns for my constructor (DONT WORRY ABOUT "X" symbols). I just would like to know how to get rows and columns from the textfile/ would like to know how to figure out how big the map is.

**I need help with the second constructor in the code:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;   // Required to get input
import java.io.File;        // Required to get input from files



    // A 2D treasure map which stores locations of treasures in an array
    // of coordinates
    public class TreasureMap{
        int rows, cols;     // How big is the treasure map
        Coord [] treasureLocations; // The locations of treasures

        Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);
      // Prompt the user for info on the treasure map and then create it

      public TreasureMap(){

          int numberOfTreasures = 0;
          System.out.println("Enter map size (2 ints): ");
          rows = kbd.nextInt(); cols = kbd.nextInt();
          System.out.println("Enter number of treasures (1 int): ");
          numberOfTreasures = kbd.nextInt();

          treasureLocations = new Coord[numberOfTreasures];

          for (int i = 0; i < numberOfTreasures; i++)
          {
              System.out.println("Enter treasure " + i + " location (2 ints): ");
              rows = kbd.nextInt(); cols = kbd.nextInt();
              treasureLocations[i] = new Coord(rows, cols);
          }
      }



      // Read the string representation of a map from a file

      public TreasureMap(String fileName) throws Exception{

          Scanner data = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
          int counter = 0;
          while(data.hasNextLine())
          {
            counter++;  
          }


      }



      // true if there is treasure at the given (r,c) coordinates, false
      // otherwise
      // This method does not require modification
      public boolean treasureAt(int r, int c){
        for(int i=0; i<treasureLocations.length; i++){
          Coord coord = treasureLocations[i];
          if(coord.row == r && coord.col == c){
        return true;
          }
        }
        return false;
      }

      // Create a string representation of the treasure map

      public String toString(){
        String [][] map = new String[this.rows][this.cols];
        for(int i=0; i<rows; i++){
          for(int j=0; j<cols; j++){
                map[i][j] = ".";
          }
        }
        for(int i=0; i<treasureLocations.length; i++){
          Coord c = treasureLocations[i];
          map[c.row][c.col] = "X";
        }
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(int i=0; i<rows; i++){
          for(int j=0; j<cols; j++){
        sb.append(map[i][j]);
          }
          sb.append("\n");
        }
        return sb.toString();
      }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's some code you can use to read lines from a file:

```
File file = new File(fileName);
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
    String line;
    int rows = 0;
    int cols = 0;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        // process the line
        rows++;
        cols = line.length(); // always the size of the last line in the file
    }
}
br.close();
```

Comment: But how to find out the dimensions of the array from a textfile? @mk.

Comment: Updated. You have to count the lines (the rows), and then you have to count the number of characters in one of the lines (which gives you the columns)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your implementation, this would give you width and height of your input file.

```
public TreasureMap(String fileName) throws Exception{
    Scanner data = new Scanner(new File(fileName));
    int width = 0;
    int height = 0;
    while(data.hasNextLine())
    {
        String line = data.nextLine();
        width = Math.max(width, line.length());
        height++;  
    }
    System.out.println(width + " x " + height);
}
```